# Корректное создание refresh токена C#

Tags: c#, авторизация, аутентификация, jwt, webapi

Для создания токена я на основе пользователя создаю список утверждений и собственно при помощи хендлера пишу его, это мне понятно, но как корректно создать refresh token? Какие утверждения туда записывать что бы я мог однозначно понять какому пользователю необходимо выдать новый токен? Может имеет смысл вообще его как-то случайно генерировать и сохранять в БД вместе с датой протухания? В общем какие способы генерации refresh токена есть?

Comment: Советую почитать [эту](https://gist.github.com/zmts/802dc9c3510d79fd40f9dc38a12bccfc) тему

Comment: Никакие данные в refresh записывать не нужно, токен обновления это просто строка связанная с юзером в бд. На месте токена может быть обычный Guid. При входе в аккаунт просто генерируйте новый Guid, и дату истечения токена, и записываете эти данные в бд тому юзеру кто залогинился.